# Apache Nifi: Update Record - Check null and replace with another parameter

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using Apache Nifi for ETL job. In my data structure, due to legacy data few fields are either null or empty. I want to populate them with some logical data. The data is as below:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "business_date": "2021-11-30",
    "order_date_time": "2021-11-30 12:10:45"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "business_date": null,
    "order_date_time": "2009-10-12 01:02:03"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "business_date": "",
    "order_date_time": "2007-01-02 03:04:05"
  }
]
```

The final result should be as below:

```json
[
  {
    "id": 1234,
    "business_date": "2021-11-30",
    "order_date_time": "2021-11-30 12:10:45"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "business_date": "2009-10-12",
    "order_date_time": "2009-10-12 01:02:03"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "business_date": "2007-01-02",
    "order_date_time": "2007-01-02 03:04:05"
  }
]
```

So based on order_date_time, need to derive business_day if it's null or empty.

I read through https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html
Everything is independent and not able to construct a solution.

Using **UpdateRecord** processor with below details:

```
/business_date --> ${field.value:isEmpty():format(/order_date_time, "YYYY-mm-dd")}
```

But this doesn't seem to work

Can anyone teach how can this be done?

Comment: you need this processor https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.9.2/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html

in addition to your link

Comment: @daggett - yes, using UpdateRecord for the same. Still not exactly getting the transition. Edited above question FYR

Answer (score 2):

[format](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#format) accepts as a first parameter a number or a Date object.

inside the link you could find following examples:

```js
{
  "eventDate" : 1508457600000
}
```

expression

```js
format( /eventDate, "yyyy-MM-dd")                                   =>  2017-10-20
```

to work with date you have to parse it from string first

```js
{
  "eventDate" : "2017-10-20 01:02:03"
}
```

expression

```js
format( toDate(/eventDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), 'yyyy-MM-dd')    =>  2017-10-20
```

so, in your case `format ( toDate )` must be used

or you could simply use `substring`

```js
/business_date --> ${field.value:isEmpty():substring(/order_date_time, 0, 10)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Used below expression with **Record Value Path** strategy

```
/business_date --> coalesce(/business_date, format(toDate(/order_date_time, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```